# Is there a template generic call operator for any posible case?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, type-traits, type-safety

I want to create a smart pointer that in case it have a function (static, lambda or member function) it can be called using "operator()", this is my first approach:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename Class>
struct TestPtrImpl {
    Class* ptr;

    TestPtrImpl(Class* ptr) : ptr(ptr) { }

    template <typename... Args>
    inline auto operator()(Args... args) {
        if (ptr) {
            if constexpr (std::is_invocable<Class, Args...>::value) {
                return ptr(args...);
            }
        }
    }
};

template <typename TClass>
TestPtrImpl<TClass> TestPtr(TClass* ptr) { return TestPtrImpl<TClass>(ptr); }

int test(string b, int a = 3) {
    cout << "Hello World" << b << a << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    cout << TestPtr(test)("h",5) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to call TestPtr(test) with only the string parameter it doesn't call the function (so default parameters seems to not work with "std::is_invocable", is there any other solution that can be used in any function case?

And, Is there an implementation of "->" that can be safe-called (like for example null conditional "?" operator in C#)?

Comment: Once you take a function pointer from a function, the default parameters "disappear". A function type depends only on the types of its arguments.

Comment: @al3c Can the default parameters be obtained in some way and then put them at the end of the calling parameter list?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Default parameters are just "syntatic sugar" the compiler adds them when you call `f(..)` with fewer arguments than retquired. You might add a template parameter pack to your class and pass them explicitly, but I can't imagine that being useful.